# How can I remove <p>&nbsp;</p> from the end of a string in C# if it's present there?

Tags: c#

Can someone help suggest how I can create a function that will trim off some text if it appears
at the end of a string in C#. What I have is some strings that end with:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

So for example `var a = "sometext<p>&nbsp;</p>";`

I know that I can use `text.EndsWith("<p>&nbsp;</p>")` to detect if it matches but then how could
I remove that?

Comment: text.Replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>", "");

Comment: @vendettamit: "from the end of a string"

Comment: It seems that my solution of `TrimEnd` would break things as it would make `"sometext<p><p>&nbsp;</p>"` become `"sometext"`, meaning it would remove the first occurance of `<p>`.

Comment: Judging by the answers, this should be an interview question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression

```
Regex.Replace(text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>$", "")
```

This way, you don't have to check `.EndsWith("<p>&nbsp;</p>")`

Comment: When I use this to have to make a new variable. For example var b = Regex.Replace(text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>$", "") ?

Comment: @Marilou Since strings are immutable, yes, a new string is created. But of course you could simply do `text = Regex.Replace(text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>$", "")` to reuse `text`.

Comment: @DominicKexel - Thank you. I will accept your answer. It looks very clean.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to only remove the tag if it is at the end of the strong, use:

```
text.Substring(0, text.Length - "<p>&nbsp;</p>".Length);
```

Comment: What if the string doesn't end in `<p>&nbsp;</p>`?

Comment: The question already has a check to see if it ends with that, so just put this inside the `if` block.

Comment: @spender, what hvd said. He beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use LastIndexOf and Substring:

```
string toReplace = "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
if(a.EndsWith(toReplace)) a.Substring(0, a.LastIndexOf(toReplace));
```

Comment: Broken. Supposing the term appears in the middle of the string?

Comment: @spender I wouldn't term that "broken" as that was never a requirement, but I've updated the answer to cover that instance

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
RemoveFromEndIfContains("<p>&nbsp;</p>");


function string RemoveFromEndIfContains(string text, string remove)
{
if (text.EndsWith())
  return text.Substring(0, text.Length - remove.Length);
else
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text.Remove(text.Length - "<p>&nbsp;</p>".Length);
```

Deletes all the characters from this string beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position.